# Range slider push to array, filter duplicates, and remove from array when range at 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to build an emotion range slider with various emotions:

[image]

When the slider is changed it adds or removes the emotion changed to an array of emotions:

The conditions for being added or removed are:

- If `selectedEmotion` array empty push `emotion` to array
- If `emotion` is not in `selectedEmotions[]` push to `selectedEmotions`
- If `emotion` is in `selectedEmotions[]` do not add a duplicate
- If `emotion.intensity` is returned to zero remove `emotion` from `selectedEmotions[]`

**Function**

```
buildEmotions(index, intensity) {
    //If selected is empty
    if (this.selectedEmotions.length >= 1) {
    //Loop through selected emotions and check for new value
    this.selectedEmotions.forEach(
        function (emotion, i) {
        //If not included in selected emotions push to array
        if (emotion.emotion_id !== this.emotions[index].emotion_id) {
            if (emotion.intensity) {
            this.selectedEmotions.push({
                emotion_id: this.emotions[index].emotion_id,
                intensitey: this.emotions[index].intensity,
                newIntensity: this.emotions[index].newIntensity
            });
            } else {
            console.log(this.selectedEmotions[i]);
            this.selectedEmotions.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        }.bind(this)
    );
    //Push new emotion to array if there are no emotions in selectedEmotions
    } else {
    this.selectedEmotions.push({
        emotion_id: this.emotions[index].emotion_id,
        intensitey: this.emotions[index].intensity,
        newIntensity: this.emotions[index].newIntensity
    });
    }
}
```

[Here's the full codepen example](https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/WNGWBXm?editors=1010)

The problem I'm having is the range slider will add duplicates, and delete  `emotions` randomly. It seems to work for the first emotion, but fails after the selected a second.

Comment: Where are duplicates added? can you provide some stronger reproducible steps here? For instance: when you do `X`, this happens. But you expected something else to happen.

To me, the code works as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 problems:

1. when you check `emotion.emotion_id !== this.emotions[index].emotion_id`, you have no `else` statement. Therefore, when chaging the same slide more than once - its intensity won't change. To fix this add:

```
else {
  emotion.intensitey = this.emotions[index].intensity;
}
```

after the closing `}` of the mentioned `if` statement.

2. You are removing elements from your array by calling `splice`. If you always want 1 element in the array - only fix problem 1. (and maybe change the array to a simple object). But if you want an array with all 3 emotions, updating on every slide update - Use the next code for your function: (it is much simpler)

```
buildEmotions(index, intensity) {
    const currentEmotion = this.selectedEmotions.find(emo => emo.emotion_id === this.emotions[index].emotion_id)
    if (currentEmotion){
      currentEmotion.intensitey = this.emotions[index].intensity;
      currentEmotion.newIntensity = this.emotions[index].newIntensity
    } else {
      this.selectedEmotions.push({
        emotion_id: this.emotions[index].emotion_id,
        intensitey: this.emotions[index].intensity,
        newIntensity: this.emotions[index].newIntensity
      });
    }
  }
```

3. This is not a bug, but notice you call it `intensitey` and `intensity`, which are two different properties.

Comment: Thank you. This is almost there. I wanted to remove elements in my array if the intensity was turned back down to zero. Sorry, it seems that I didn't articulate my post very well, but you have managed to understand my intentions

Comment: I added an `if(intensity === 0)` statement, but for some reason the `this.selectedEmotions[index]` is turning up as undefined.

https://codepen.io/Corbin/pen/zYKVQWO?editors=1011

Comment: Your example  is not reproducing the undefined you mentioned

Comment: Adjust a slider to any number and then back to 0. It should delete the emotion in the `selectedEmotions` array. But instead I get an undefined error. For some reason `index` isn't working as a key for the `selectedEmotions` array, so I can't use it to splice the array.

Comment: OK, I see the problem in your example. The problem is that `index` is not index of selectedEmotions, but it is index of emotions. So just replace your splice command with this: `this.selectedEmotions.splice(this.selectedEmotions.indexOf(currentEmotion), 1);`